# Merge Two TinyDB Databases

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, file, tinydb

On Python, I'm trying to merge multiple JSON files obtained from TinyDB.

I was not able to find a way to directly merge two tinydb JSON files that have keys autogenerated in the sequence that not restart with the opening of the next file.

In code words, i want to merge large amount of data like this:

```
 hello1={"1":"bye",2:"good"....,"20000":"goodbye"}    

    hello2={"1":"dog",2:"cat"....,"15000":"monkey"}
```

As:

```
Hello3= {"1":"bye",2:"good"....,"20000":"goodbye","20001":"dog",20002:"cat"....,"35000":"monkey"}
```

Because of the problem to find the correct way to do it with TinyDB, I opened and transformed them simply in classic syntax json file, loading each file and then doing:

```
Data = Data['_default']
```

The problem that I have, is that at the moment the code works, but it has serious memory problems. After a few seconds, the created merged Db contains like 28Mb of data, but (probably) the cache saturate, and it starts to add all the other data in a really slow way.

So, I need to empty the cache after a certain amount of data, or probably i need to change the way to do this!

That's the code that i use:

```
Try1.purge()
Try1 = TinyDB('FullDB.json')

with open('FirstDataBase.json') as Part1 :
     Datapart1 = json.load(Part1)
     Datapart1 = Datapart1['_default']

     for dets in range(1, len(Datapart1)):

         Try1.insert(Datapart1[str(dets)])


with open('SecondDatabase.json') as Part2:
     Datapart2 = json.load(Part2)
     Datapart2 = Datapart2['_default']

     for dets in range(1, len(Datapart2)):

         Try1.insert(Datapart2[str(dets)])
```

Answer (score -1):

> **Question**: Merge Two TinyDB Databases ... probably i need to change the way to do this!

---

> From [TinyDB Documentation](https://tinydb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html)
>   **Why Not Use TinyDB?**
>   ...
>   **You are really concerned about performance and need a high speed database.**

Single row insertion into a DB are always slow, try `db.insert_multiple(...`.
The second one. with `generator`. gives you the option to hold down the memory footprint.

```
# From list
Try1.insert_multiple([{"1":"bye",2:"good"....,"20000":"goodbye"}])
```

or

```
# From generator function
Try1.insert_multiple(generator())
```